# Syncing app state with clients using socketio

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, synchronization, diff

I'm running a node server with SocketIO which keeps a large object (app state) that is updated regularly.

All clients receive the object after connecting to the server and should keep it updated in real-time using the socket (read-only).

Here's what I have considered:

**1:**
Emit a delta of changes to the clients using `diff` after updates
(requires dealing with the reability of delivery and lost updates)

**2:**
Use the `diffsync` package (however it allows clients to push changes to the server, but I need updates to be unidirectional, i.e. server-->clients)

I'm confident there should be a readily available solution to deal with this but I was not able to find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very easy. You must [modify the server](https://github.com/janmonschke/diffsync/blob/master/src/server.js#L117) so that it accepts updates only from trusted clients.

```
let Server = require('diffsync').Server;
let receiveEdit  = Server.prototype.receiveEdit 
Server.receiveEdit = function(connection, editMessage, sendToClient){
  if(checkIsTrustedClient(connection))
    receiveEdit.call(this, connection, editMessage, sendToClient)
}
```

[but](https://github.com/janmonschke/diffsync/blob/master/src/server.js#L159-L162)

```
    // TODO: implement backup workflow
    // has a low priority since `packets are not lost` - but don't quote me on that :P
    console.log('error', 'patch rejected!!', edit.serverVersion, '->', 
            clientDoc.shadow.serverVersion, ':',
            edit.localVersion, '->', clientDoc.shadow.localVersion);
```

Second option is try find another solution based on [`jsondiffpatch`](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/jsondiffpatch)